# Convert date so that jquery calender value can be set as the date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I have a date in the format: `2014-11-21T00:00:00.000Z` that I need to place into a [jquery calender/datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

I have been trying to set it using:

```
document.getElementById("startdate").valueAsDate(2014-11-25T00:00:00.000Z)
```

AND

```
$('#startdate').val("2014-11-25T00:00:00.000Z")
```

But to no avail. How can I populate the date picker with the date?

Comment: datepickers usually have a `setDate` method  http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`setDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) method:

```
$('#startdate').datepicker();
var dateText = "2014-11-25T00:00:00.000Z";
var actualDate = new Date(dateText);
var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate() + 1);
$('#startdate').datepicker('setDate', newDate);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/xsp48tby/1/)

Also note, javascript day numbers start at 0 which is why we +1 on the day.